# Why doesn't this work?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to change the value of an element with javascript.

```
<span id="mixui_title">Angry cow sound?</span>


<script type="text/javascript">
$("#mixui_title").val("very happy cow");
</script>
```

Comment: How are you triggering the change?

Comment: @Virat A trigger is not needed in this example.

Comment: Question headline could be better...

Comment: As noted by others and +1 by me, span has text, not value, inputs contain value (val), use .text instead.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the text method instead:

```
$("#mixui_title").text("very happy cow");
```

Answer (score 2):

Try [html()](http://docs.jquery.com/Attributes/html) function instead :

```
<span id="mixui_title">Angry cow sound?</span>

<script type="text/javascript">
$("#mixui_title").html("very happy cow");
</script>
```

Comment: Text might be more appropriate here.  But then again, that might be slicing hairs.

Answer (score 1):

2 Things:

1- Usualy, javascript is placed at the top of the page. If you do this in the future, you'll need to need to enclose it in the jQuery equivalent of document.ready:

```
 $(function() {
//  do stuff
 });
```

This tells jQuery to run the function as soon as the document is ready.

2- For any value between two opening/closing tags, you need to use the jQuery method .html("enter text to change") while the .val() method is used to change the value of any control with the attribute value="" like inputs:

```
<input type="submit value="This will be changed with val()" />
```

The following should work fine. Note its wrapped in $(function() { }); and is using the .html() property and is placed at the top of the page.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function(){
    $("#mixui_title").html("very happy cow");
});
</script>

<span id="mixui_title">Angry cow sound?</span>
```

Comment: Actually, for performance reasons JavaScript should be placed at the bottom of the page. See: http://developer.yahoo.com/performance/rules.html#js_bottom

Comment: JavaScript should typically be placed at the bottom of the page to increase page render times.  See: http://developer.yahoo.com/performance/rules.html#js_bottom

Answer (score -1):

It's not enclosed by the

```
$(document).ready(function(){ 
   //your code goes here 
});
```

Comment: not needed if the script is placed after the element in the page, like submitters example